# How to achieve label embededd in UIImageView in iOS Swift like shown in image?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uikit, uilabel

[image: Edit Button/Label inside UIImageView]

I want to achieve label/Button embededd in UIImageView in iOS Swift like shown in image.Has anyone done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a square `UIView` with `clipsToBounds` property set to `YES` which contains `UIImageView` and `UILabel`. The image view should cover all the view frame. The label should be positioned at the bottom of the view over the image view. Then just set appropriate corner radius (half of the view's height) for the view's layer and set its `masksToBounds` property to `YES`. That's it

Answer (score 2):

You just need to play with UIView, UILabel And UIImageView.

You view hierarchy will be like below...

```
- UIView (mainView)
   - UIImageView (imageView)
   - UILabel
```

You need to make `mainView.clipsToBounds = true` so that after giving corner radius to it, it's subview will not go beyond its superview's bounds.

For imageView, you can set its content mode to aspect fill/ aspect fit as per your requirement.